# Round according to nearest decimal value - java

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I have used this one

```
Math.round(input * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

but it didn't work with my requirement. I want to round into two decimal points according to nearest decimal value.

firstly I want to check fourth decimal value
if it is 5 or above I want to add 1 into 3rd decimal value
then want to check 3rd one
if it is 5 or above I want to add 1 into 2nd one

ex: if I have 22.3246

refer above example number. 4th decimal no is 6.
we can add 1 into 3rd decimal value.

result : 22.325

now 3rd decimal no is 5. we can add 1 into 2nd decimal value

result : 22.33

I want to get result 22.33

Comment: Are you aware that your desired result, 22.33 is (in terms of distance to the original value) worse than the standard rounding result of 22.32?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff ya I know that. but this is the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to respect the 4th decimal digit, you can do it in this way:

```
double val = Math.round(22.3246 * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
double result = Math.round(val * 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(result); // print: 22.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` class to accomplish this task, in combination with a scale and `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.

Sample code:

```java
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("22.3246").divide(BigDecimal.ONE,3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                    .divide(BigDecimal.ONE,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Output:

```java
22.33
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, the greatest number to be rounded down to `22.32` is `22.3244444444...`. From `22.32444...4445` on, iteratively rounding digit per digit will lead to `22.33`.

So, you can add a bias of `0.005 - 0.0044444444` (standard rounding threshold minus your threshold), being `5/9000` and then round to the next `1/100` the standard way:

```
    double BIAS = 5.0 / 9000.0;
    double result = Math.round((input + BIAS) * 100.0) / 100.0;
```